# Acceder a elementos tokenfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy creando `tags` de productos mediante una búsqueda Ajax, similar a `stackoverflow`

```
$('#_keytags').tokenfield({
        autocomplete: {
        source: function(request,response){
            $.ajax({
                url: routes(4,2),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data:{keys: request.term},
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                } 
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event,ui){

        },
        delay: 100
      },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });
```

> Mi pregunta es como puedo agregarles un `id` a estos `tags` y como
>   recorrer estos elementos obteniendo su `id`?

Comment: Pregunta demasiado amplia: si las etiquetas se guardan en una tabla, la tabla deberá tener una columna id que sea la PK... pero obviamente eso no tiene nada que ver con jquery o bootstrap

Comment: Si te das cuenta quiero enviar `id`, no nombres! , por eso la pregunta `¿como asignar y recorrer?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ajax donde recibe los datos despues de pintarlos puedes usar ese mismo data para recorrer y buscar los label que tengan el mismo nombre que el data.nombre por ejemplo:

```
success: function(data){
     response(data);
     $.each(data,function(i,item){
        $('#_keytags label:contains("'+item.nombre+'")').attr('data-id',item.id);
     });
},
```

Lo que hace es buscar los labels que contengan el texto igual que los datos que recibes y si lo encuentra, pues le asigna el data-id correspondiente como atributo. Siempre y cuando el texto este contenido en un label, si esta en un span cambias label a span, y asi con tu caso concreto.

Y ya por ultimo con un:

```
var array = array();
$("#_keytags label").each(function(i,item){
    array.push($(item).attr('data-id'));
});
```

Recorres todos los data-id de los labels y lo guardas en un array

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de la librería que estás utilizando [(enlace)](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#usage), tienes la posibilidad de definir un "value" y un "label", donde el value sería tu "id":

```
$('#myField').tokenfield('setTokens', [
  { value: "blue", label: "Blau" }, 
  { value: "red", label: "Rot" }
]);
```